# Pgfplots: grouped bar-charts using single addplot

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, csv

I have a single `.csv` data file, with contents alike this:

```
Time, Value 
0, 7.130000000000109
0, 7.634999999999309
0, 6.040000000000873
...
1, 5.5900000000001455
1, 6.0649999999996
1, 6.204999999999018
...
n, 5...
n, 6...
n, 7...
```

And I'm trying to plot a grouped bar-chart of this data, such that all the y-values (`Value`) with the same x-value (`Time`) are grouped.

Thus far I'm plotting using this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\addplot table [y=Value] {\datafile};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But the result is overlapping bars (rather than the bars being grouped next to one another).
[image: Overlapping Bar Charts]

Answer (score 1):

Figured my data was regular; `m` readings for each unique `Time` value, so I ended up doing this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\foreach \n in {1,...,m} {
    \addplot+[each nth point=10, filter discard warning=false,
              unbounded coords=discard, color={blue}]
        table [y index = 1,skip first n={\n}] {\datafile};
}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It's not exactly a pleasing solution, but it does seem to be working somewhat:

[image: Overlapping fixed somewhat]